# error in for loop java

Tags: java, for-loop

How to eliminate this error?

```
int i, start, sum = 0, min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(i = 0, start = 0; i < n, start < n; i++, start++) {
    if(a[i]!=start) {
        sum+=a[i];
        if(sum>max)
            max=sum;
         if(sum<min) 
             min=sum;
    }
}
```

The above code shows the following error in for loop.

> 22: error: ';' expected  22: error: ')' expected  22: error: > expected 22: error: ';' expected  22: error: illegal start of expression  22: error: ';' expected

Comment: my guess this is your problem: i<n,start<n. change it to : i < n && start < n;

Comment: Im surprised it even compiles

Comment: What's the point in having `i` and `start` if they always have the same value?

Comment: @Greggz it doesn't.

Comment: what do you think the compiler gets from this ***for(i=0,start=0;i<n,start<n;i++,start++)***

Comment: @Stultuske Works now....

Comment: The code doesnot work because for loop cannot have 2 Independent conditions , it must be i<n|start<n or i<n& start<n. however Andy is right your program can run with single value i or start there is no need to have two values.

Comment: I know that loop doesn't work. But I just try that to know whether multiple statements in for loop works on Java.

Comment: in the condition you have to use && because it is returning a  Boolean

Answer (score 0):

This is the general rules for for loops.

1) You can have multiple initializations

2) You cannot have multiple conditions (having comma separated)

3) You can have multiple increments.

So an example would be

`for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < this.board.length; i++, j++)`
This answer your question and ones who hits the same questions in the future.

Comment: you removed the second condition

Comment: @BasilBattikhi , what have I removed..?I told only one condition should be there cannot have something like this ( i< 10, j>5).

Comment: start variables has a different calculation

Answer (score 0):

You can have only 1 termination in the for statement itself.
As you are putting a "," between them I believe you want them both to be true so just replace that "," by "&&".
You can have mulitple initializations & increments but only 1 termination condition so there you can use AND (&&), OR (||).

Answer (score 0):

```
int i,start=0, sum = 0, min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++,) {
if(a[i]!=start) {
    sum+=a[i];
    if(sum>max)
        max=sum;
     if(sum<min) 
         min=sum;
 }
}
start = i;
```

Start would now also have the same value as i (if you need it any place ahead), and this could would compile without errors.

Comment: You can not use 2 **conditions** in the same **loop**, you can use multiple **initializations** and multiple **increments**. Hope i helped.